# drupal commerce kickstart installation from scratch

Tags: drupal, commerce-kickstart

I am new to Drupal, and trying to learn and create Drupal commerce site locally and practice in it. Can anyone suggest simple steps to install it? I tried using Composer but it is a bit complex for me and keeps on showing errors.

tried to install it with these steps:  docs.drupalcommerce.org but seems complex for me. can't find any proper latest YouTube videos either. also asked for chat gpt but the simple site got installed when trying to install commerce it asked for an address, commerceguy addressing, token, drush, [preflight] Package "drupal/core" is not installed.